# Justify text inside JOptionPane

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I have the following line of code

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Código incorreto\nPor favor verifique", "Atenção", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
```

that show this message here

[image]

How to center this 2 lines of text in the center of the box?

Comment: Waiting for you who voted down explain how to improve my question

Comment: Maybe use JFrame as rootPane, and or try to change Look and Feels.

Answer (score 3):

```
JLabel label = new JLabel("<html><center>Código incorreto<br>Por favor verifique");
label.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, label, "Atenção", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
```

Try this one. Preview:

[image]

Comment: @RoshanaPitigala I am aware of this, but he mentions that he wants center (in main post). @ OP if you need justify, let me know to delete my post.

Comment: and btw if you are using html you don't need JLabel at all

Comment: @RoshanaPitigala You do. Without JLabel and its horizontal alignment, Jlabel has only centered text. OP asks how to move it to the center of the dialog. So, you need the `label.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);`

Answer (score 0):

You may get it working with following code:

```
String message = "<html><body><div width='100px' align='center'>Código incorreto<br>Por favor verifique</div></body></html>";
JLabel messageLabel = new JLabel(message);
JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, messageLabel, "Atenção", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION);
```

Comment: @Max I've tested. It is working. The error message is in the center. Don't know what else have you wanted?? :(

Comment: Dont worry, thanks for your help, man. I will continue trying to find

Comment: @Max Can you please make us clear about your desired output?